# Query takes too long to run

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running the below query to retrive the unique latest result based on a date field within a same table. But this query takes too much time when the table is growing. Any suggestion to improve this is welcome.

```
select
    t2.*
from
    (
        select
            (
                select
                    id
                from
                    ctc_pre_assets ti
                where
                    ti.ctcassettag = t1.ctcassettag
                order by
                    ti.createddate desc limit 1
            ) lid
        from
            (
                select
                    distinct ctcassettag
                from
                    ctc_pre_assets
            ) t1
    ) ro,
    ctc_pre_assets t2
where
    t2.id = ro.lid
order by
    id
```

Our able may contain same row multiple times, but each row with different time stamp. My object is based on a single column for example assettag I want to retrieve single row for each assettag with latest timestamp.

Comment: Please provide the table definitions and the EXPLAIN output.

Comment: have you tried to use indexes?

Comment: After adding index it is ok, But still it is slow. Takes more than 20 sec

Comment: Can any `ctcassettag` ever have more than one row with the same `createddate`?  In other words, can two rows ever be jointly newest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simpler, and probably faster, to find the newest date for each `ctcassettag` and then join back to find the whole row that matches.

This does assume that no `ctcassettag` has multiple rows with the same `createddate`, in which case you *can* get back more than one row per `ctcassettag`.

```
SELECT
    ctc_pre_assets.*
FROM
    ctc_pre_assets
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        ctcassettag,
        MAX(createddate)   AS createddate
    FROM
        ctc_pre_assets
    GROUP BY
        ctcassettag
)
   newest
       ON  newest.ctcassettag = ctc_pre_assets.ctcassettag
       AND newest.createddate = ctc_pre_assets.createddate
ORDER BY
    ctc_pre_assets.id
```

**EDIT:** To deal with multiple rows with the same date.

You haven't actually said how to pick which row you want in the event that multiple rows are for the same `ctcassettag` on the same `createddate`.  So, this solution just chooses the row with the lowest `id` from amongst those `duplicates`.

```
SELECT
    ctc_pre_assets.*
FROM
    ctc_pre_assets
WHERE
    ctc_pre_assets.id
    =
    (
        SELECT
            lookup.id
        FROM
            ctc_pre_assets   lookup
        WHERE
            lookup.ctcassettag = ctc_pre_assets.ctcassettag
        ORDER BY
            lookup.createddate  DESC,
            lookup.id           ASC
        LIMIT
            1
    )
```

This does still use a *correlated* sub-query, which is slower than a simple nested-sub-query *(such as my first answer)*, but it does deal with the "duplicates".

You can change the rules on which row to pick by changing the `ORDER BY` in the correlated sub-query.

It's also very similar to your own query, but with one less join.

Comment: thanks. but your query returns duplicate values if the time is exactly matches. But I want only single entry.

Comment: Can you please help on that?

Comment: @Rajesh - Then you should have answered my comment asking about the the data ;)  Also, I believe that they won't be duplicates, they'll have different `id`'s.  So, the question becomes, how do *you* want to choose which row to return?  If two rows are for the same `ctcassettag` and have the same `createddate`, *which one do you want*?

Comment: In that case max ID

Comment: @Rajesh Then change the `ASC` to `DESC` in the second code example.

Comment: Thanks, It's working fine. But for table with 10,000 rows it took 4 seconds to respond. I added index on id and ctcassettag. Is this ok? Or still tuning required?

Comment: @Rajesh - I would use a single compound index covering `(ctcassettag, createddate, id)`.

Answer (score 0):

Nested queries are always known to take longer time than a conventional query since. Can you append 'explain' at the start of the query and put your results here? That will help us analyse the exact query/table which is taking longer to response.

Check if the table has indexes. Unindented tables are not advisable(until unless obviously required to be unindented) and are alarmingly slow in executing queries.

On the contrary, I think the best case is to avoid writing nested queries altogether. Bette, run each of the queries separately and then use the results(in array or list format) in the second query.

Comment: This should probably be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Table already has index. As you suggested let me try by executing separate queries.

Comment: Nested queries do not necessitate longer execution times or more costly explain plans.  This belief tends to arise from not understanding how explain plans are generated.  That lack of knowledge means it is easy to write a poorly performing query and not know why.  For example `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE x = 1) AS x1 WHERE y = 2` will perform the same as using `SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE x = 1 AND y = 2`.  Invariably, nested queries perform badly because they include calculations that obfuscate indexes or are otherwise badly written, not simply because they are nested.

Answer (score 0):

First some questions that you should at least ask yourself, but maybe also give us an answer to improve the accuracy of our responses:

1. Is your data normalized? If yes, maybe you should make an exception to avoid this brutal subquery problem
2. Are you using indexes? If yes, which ones, and are you using them to the fullest?

Some suggestions to improve the readability and maybe performance of the query:
 - Use joins
 - Use group by
 - Use aggregators

Example (untested, so might not work, but should give an impression):

```
 SELECT t2.*
 FROM (
    SELECT id 
    FROM ctc_pre_assets 
    GROUP BY ctcassettag 
    HAVING createddate = max(createddate) 
    ORDER BY ctcassettag DESC 
 ) ro
 INNER JOIN ctc_pre_assets t2 ON t2.id = ro.lid
 ORDER BY id
```

Using normalization is great, but there are a few caveats where normalization causes more harm than good. This seems like a situation like this, but without your tables infront of me, I can't tell for sure.

Using distinct the way you are doing, I can't help but get the feeling you might not get all relevant results - maybe someone else can confirm or deny this?

It's not that subqueries are all bad, but they tend to create massive scaleability issues if written incorrectly. Make sure you use them the right way (google it?)

Indexes can potentially save you for a bunch of time - if you actually use them. It's not enough to set them up, you have to create queries that actually uses your indexes. Google this as well.

Comment: Your inner query (`ro`) uses `LIMIT 1` and so can only return one row.  The Op's query, however, returns one row for ***each*** unique `ctcassettag`.

Comment: @MatBailie You are absolutely right, slipped my mind. But removing the LIMIT 1 altogether would return the correct result right?

Comment: I'd have to try it to see, but possibly, due to certain behaviours in MySQL.  You may need `ORDER BY MAX(createddate)` or something like that, I'm not sure without trying it.  But most relevant is whether this behaviour is guaranteed to be deterministic, and it's not.  Though this "trick" works nearly all the time, the documentation does say you can't actually *rely* on it *always* working.  In fact it explicitly says it's "indeterminate".

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html : `In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate, which is probably not what you want.`